# Can we shorten scripts in /etc/sudoers?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, sudo, sudoers

(This question is related to my homework last semester, so please do not mention the risk.)

I faced to this:

```
    ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/vim /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf
```

Is there any way to shorten this script like this:

```
    ALL=(ALL) vim httpd.conf
```

I attempted to use command alias, but it did not work. If it is not possible, could you explain why not?

Comment: More commonly than spelling out `/usr/bin/vim`, you would specify `sudoedit /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf`.  Provided your `$EDITOR` environment variable is set you would then do `sudoedit /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf`  That allows you to change editors more easily.

Comment: It looks more useful because I do not have to write /usr/bin/vim again and again when I specify more than one file. Also, I do not have to rewrite all of them.

Comment: But you have to make a habit of editing the file with `sudoedit httpd.conf` instead of `sudo vim httpd.conf`

Comment: I do not think it is a serious problem. I cannot use sudo vim if I do not write ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/vim /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf in sudoers.

Comment: Voted to close; not programming-related. (Vim has been explicitly approved as a SO topic, but this question is more about sudo than Vim.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, for the same reason a greeting card addressed to "My friend Joe" is not going to be delivered by the post office: the OS has no idea which `vim` you are refering to. `PATH` does not apply because it only works on invocation.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to tell OS pathes? PATH does not work, but I suspect that I can use a substitution.

Comment: If you were allowed to do this, the user could put their own `vim` program in their `$PATH`. It could do things that you don't really want to allow the user to do.